# When I reload UIWebView I get a Signal SIGABRT in my main.h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, reload

Here are my files. When I click the reload button it goes into what I understand is a segfault in OBJC. I don't think it is the website but something in the main that is not being met/returned. It gives the SIGABRT in the main.m file. I've tried to enable zombies to no avail and if that is the way to go please let me know.

```
//
//  main.m
//  webKitExp
//
//  Created by J.Doe on 8/14/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 J.Doe. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

//
//  ViewController.h
//  webKitExp
//
//  Created by J.Doe
//  Copyright © 2017 J.Doe. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end

//
//  ViewController.m
//  webKitExp
//
//  Created by J.Doe on 8/14/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 J.Doe. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
 NSString *localURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index"  ofType:@"html"];
 NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL   fileURLWithPath:localURL]];
 [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
 [webView reload];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


@end
```

Comment: The index.html file is probably not being found. Try to load a web page instead of a local file and see if you get the same error

Comment: try this instead? [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

Comment: I tried the webView loadRequest too but that didn't work and as far as the index.html file goes, it's in the same file and loads the first time fine, it just doesn't reload and crashes instead

Comment: But what happens if you change it to a web request just say google.com and fire the reload action. If it doesn't crash then it has to be something with the local file, if it does crash then maybe something with your action in interface builder is messed up.

Comment: yea actually when I change it to google, it doesn't load because I currently don't have wifi on the device, but also still crashes when I hit the reload button.

Comment: Alright then your issue lies in the IBAction / Button associated with it. As others have said you should be using WKWebview but that shouldn't be the reason this crash is occurring

Comment: when I changed everything to WKWebView it still crashes on reloading or doesn't reload. Also the original reload that was in the index.html file doesn't seem to be working nor getting called. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ios8+ you should use WKWebview instead of UIWebview. @Henly ans is in Swift3 ,here is the Objective-C version of the same.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     _wkWebview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];  
     _wkWebview.navigationDelegate = self ;
     [self.view addSubview:_wkWebview ];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [_wkWebview loadRequest:request];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(reload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Reload" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 200.0, 50.0, 50.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)reload{
     [self.wkWebview reload];
}
```

Do not forget to import WebKit to make it working `#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>`
Do let me know if you any queries in comment. I will try and help.

Comment: oddly enough now my button doesn't show up. I took my version out and replaced it with the programmatically created one that you suggested and now it doesn't show up at all

Comment: -figured it out, it was defaulting to white and not showing up against the background it shows up but something is off about the reload

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using WKWebview instead of UIWebview for apps running iOS 8+.

This is an example of using WKWebview within a UIViewController. Hitting the reload button (with or with our network connection) doesn't crash the app.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebviewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var wkWebview : WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        wkWebview = WKWebView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
        wkWebview?.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(wkWebview!)

        let url = URL.init(string:"https://www.google.com")
        let urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: url!)

        wkWebview?.load(urlRequest)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 50, y: 200, width: 50, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Reload", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reload), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.layer.zPosition = 101
    }

    func reload() {
        self.wkWebview?.reload()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

Shouldn't be too hard to convert that to Objective-C.

There is also a WKNavigationDelegate method

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
        didFailProvisionalNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
        withError:(NSError *)error
```

which gets invoked when there is no internet access. You may want to implement that.